# Hide images for articles that are older than two weeks

Tags: 7, theming

I have a news website built on Drupal 7. I need to hide all images on this website's articles, when the articles are older than two weeks.

I believe a solution would a PHP line to add to the articles' template.

The line would check a article date and add `display:none` to the CSS styles of all images.

Unfortunately, I don't know PHP.

Could someone please help me with the line?

Comment: `display:none` will cause the images not to be displayed, but the files will still be available and can be accessed by checking the page's HTML.  Is that good enough?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Unfortunately, we don't aim to write code on demand. We can answer questions about code that doesn't work, when we see the code actually used. Keep in mind that, even in this case, the question is acceptable if the answer is Drupal-specific. If the answer is that, for example, the short array syntax requires at least PHP 5.4, then the question isn't anymore Drupal-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7's *.tpl templates still support PHP. If you have access to those templates, wrap printing the images in an according `if` condition statement. You'll wan't to compare the article creation time with the current time minus two weeks. The article creation time (assuming you use nodes), is saved as UNIX timestamp in the `created` property:

```
<?php if ($node->created < strtotime('-2 weeks')): ?>
  // Your image print statement(s) here.
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will prevent the images from being added to the output, rather than just hiding the images. It is more desirable, as it may safe traffic in the visitors' browser.

Please note, that above example is NOT taking time zones into account.

Read more about the [if construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), the [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) PHP function and possible alternatives with time zone support in the PHP documentation (as teaching PHP actually isn't the scope of this Drupal group).

Comment: I can't remember a thing about Drupal 7 caching, but if a post is cached with the image, the version without the image may not be displayed until cache is cleared.